# When I import Swagger API to Postman, all request names end up blank in Postman GUI

Tags: api, import, swagger, postman

I am QA engineer. The Dev team produces documentation for our product's RESTful API using Swagger. I need to import this to Postman to make it easy to invoke the product's API.

After importing the JSON file (in Swagger format) into Postman, there is 1 but big problem: **All titles (and descriptions) of individual requests are blank! (see screen shot below).**

[image]

Apparently, this is a known issue, documented here: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1434

We have literally hundreds of requests. I need to find a sufficiently effective yet simple way to ensure all request titles in Postman are populated with a value which I would like to calculate on the fly.

I have been considering the following approach:

> Write a command line tool (using NodeJS or another
>   solid platform) which will receive:
>       1. ID of the collection to fix
>       2. api key
>
> It will iterate through all requests in the
>   collection.  For each request: if Name field is
>   blank, then a substring of  the request URL
>   will be assigned to the Name field; if name is
>   not blank, the request is left alone.
>
> What I am unsure about:
>
> 1. Can I do this programmatically from Postman? It does not make sense to put this code into any one individual request (as pre or post).
>
> (If I have to code this util outside of Postman)
>
> 2. For NodeJS there are "postman-collection" and
>      "postman-sdk" but I am slightly confused which I
>      should use.
> 3. Unfortunately, I have not yet found any suitable > library for maintaining Postman collections using C# > or Java.

I am quite frankly confused by the available options. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, solved it thanks to Ian T Price solution (just copy `operationId` value into a new key `summary`). I decided to write a little javascript utility for this:

```
function swagPostman(swaggerJson) {
  for (let path in swaggerJson.paths) {
    let methods = ["get", "head", "post", "put", "delete", "connect", "options", "trace", "patch"];

    methods.map(method => {
      if ((swaggerJson.paths[path] || {})[method]) {
        swaggerJson.paths[path][method].summary =
          swaggerJson.paths[path][method].operationId;
      }
    });
  }

  return JSON.stringify(swaggerJson);
}
```

Also made a simple pen where to run the script with a GUI: https://codepen.io/0x616c65/full/pMaQpb. You just copy-paste your swagger.json file in that pen and woilà!

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer to this is to add a line `summary: <RequestName>`

I came across this problem using the excellent [APIs-Gurus OpenAPIDirectory repo](https://github.com/APIs-guru/openapi-directory)

These swagger.yaml files have a `operationId:` line which can be duplicated and the key replaced with `summary:` using:

```
awk '{if (!/      operationId:/) {print ; next} ; { print; a=gensub(/      operationId:/, "      summary:",1) ; print a}}' swagger.yaml  > swagger-new.yaml
```

Importing this into Postman then shows the correct request name.

PostMan is separating out the Import/Export functions in to separate plug-ins but their plug-in model leaves a ***lot*** to be desired at the current time.